# Can I use NVM without admin rights

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, nvm

I don't have admin rights, and NVM was installed by the admin

So if I want to use NVM, can I use it?

If there are some changes that I want to make (in environment variables for example) I can make it by using admin credentials once.

But each and every time I can't get admin credentials. So if there are one time change I can make it

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I find out that I can't use NVM without admin credentials,

You should have rights to switch between node versions using NVM

Answer (score 1):

there is a library which enables switching between node versions without requiring admin rights and without enablind developer mode on windows - https://github.com/jchip/nvm

keep in mind to delete your old nvm installation beforehand

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I solved in a few different ways. Ultimately I ended up with the last solution as the permanent one

Solution 1. Enable developer mode on Windows

This is based on the issue/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038683/allow-mklink-for-a-non-admin-user). Note that you need a newer version of Windows 10 in order for this to work.

Solution 2. Change the nodejs nvm symlink location.

By default the symlink location is on the C: drive/programfiles. This is protected by Windows so it's not modified by non-admin users. If you place the symlink outside the program files location into a folder where non-admin users have read and write capabilities, you should be fine.

Solution 3. Disable UAC (User Account Control) // Not Recommended

You can disable the UAC control so that you don't get the admin rights prompt. Generally should be avoided because of security concerns. That being said if you need it solved in a pinch this is the short-term solution

Solution 4. Add read and write permission to the symlink folder

Going to the folder properties and selecting the security tab, you can add read and write permissions for non-admin users. Similar to solution number 2.

Solution 5. aka the workaround using [Volta](https://volta.sh/)

Rust-based does the same thing as nvm. Doesnt require admin rights, only suggests you run it in developer mode. Uses a shim in order to intercept any nodejs commands. I ended up using this as the long-term solution

Answer (score -1):

- Download NVM for Windows
  You can find the latest releases at this link.
  [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)
- For this special case,
  you can download the file nvm-noinstall.zip.
  Extract the zip file into your favorite folder for this kind of tool.
  On my machine, I have a main folder called "tools" on my root with other tools as well
- Add two environment variables,
  the first one, is called [NVM_HOME] and this is the patch of NVM. In our case is c:\tools\nvm.
  The other variable is called [NVM_SYMLINK] and it must be a directory should not exist, like c:\tools\nvm\nodejs.
- Now you can update the Patch value in the path with the two new values:
  %NVM_HOME%
  %NVM_SYMLINK%
- If you want you can create a file called "settings.txt" in the nvm directory and it uses that file like User Environment Variables.
  It prevents to restart the machine but it's not mandatory.
  The example below is the content of my settings.txt file.
  As you can see contains the same parameters values of the environment variables.

  root: C:\tools\nvm
  path: C:\tools\nvm\nodejs
  arch: 64
  proxy: none

now run cmd and enter nvm it should work.

that works for me. give it a try [how to make nvm works without admin rights](https://dev.to/kasuken/install-node-version-manager-nvm-without-admin-rights-194f)